# Is there any alternative to Cross Join in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, cross-join

I have two tables `Table1` and `Table2` where i need to find all the rows which satisfies the condition **Fuzzy_Qgram**(Approximate matching optimization) between `Table1.LastName` and `Table2.LastName`

**Here is my Query :**

```
Select * from Table1 
Cross Join
Table2
Where Fuzzy_Qgram(Table1.LastName,Table2.LastName)> =1.5
```

In this query, Each row in `Table1` is multipled with each row in `Table2` and the rows which satisfy `Fuzzy_Qgram(Table1.LastName,Table2.LastName)> =1.5` will be returned.

The Execution of query is very slow as i have more than **300,000 rows**  in `Table1` and **3000 rows** in `Table2`

Is there any alternative to `Cross Join` for such queries for better and faster  optimization?

Comment: Your fn is scalar, and I would expect problem there. Could you move the 'fuzzy' logic to e.g. Cross apply?

Comment: Nope, `Table2` is a *view* not a table. Sorry about that, a typing mistake.

Comment: @Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić  : Yes , it returns a scalar value on which i am applying condition

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus : There is no improvement, it takes same time or even longer to execute

Comment: Simply put, if your fuzzy function isn't too complex, there is a chance to extract that logic into query and speed it up. Say, 'select * from t1 cross join t2 cross apply (select fuzzy_qgram = ... Logic ...) ext where ext.fuzzy_qgram >= 1.5'

Comment: I will try that, but is there a way to avoid `Cross join` for my same query

Comment: Look, your requirement is test each row with each row, right? That is cartesian product (here cartesian square) and using `cross join` is just one way to do it. Another way is `join on 1=1`. Another way is `select * from t t1, t t2`. You can't do much about that. Speedup can be done by modifying operation to be set-based instead item-based.

Comment: G Mastros: Yes , either way i get the same results

Comment: @user42995 Have you tried the query I suggested?  Is it any faster?

Comment: I am running, but its taking more time. What does `Table.LastName <= Table2.LastName` do?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, my advice is probably not right.  If you had been joining the same table to itself, it probably would have reduced the execution time, but with different tables, it will probably return incorrect (incomplete) results.

Comment: Can you show the code for the Fuzzy_Qgram function?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does the order of parameters to the function make a difference?  I mean, when you run the following query, are you guaranteed to get the same results?

```
Select Fuzzy_Qgram('Washington','Obama')
Select Fuzzy_Qgram('Obama','Washington')
```

If so, then there shouldn't be any reason to test it both ways, so you could change your query to:

```
Select * 
from   Table1 
       Inner join Table2
         On Table.LastName <= Table2.LastName
Where Fuzzy_Qgram(Table1.LastName,Table2.LastName)> =1.5
```

Of course, I have no idea what Fuzzy_Qgram does, so you will want to test this thoroughly.  If this is correct, it will probably reduce your execution time by approximately 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

To cut the long story short.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
 Table1 t1
 JOIN Table2 t2
  ON 1=1
 CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 
    fuzzy_qgram = t1.someColumnOf_t1 + t2.someColumnOf_t2
 ) ext 
WHERE ext.fuzzy_qgram >= 1.5
```

Of course, you have to replace `t1.someColumnOf_t1 + t2.someColumnOf_t2` with your fuzzy_qgram logic.
Use this and there is a chance you will see significant speedup.